# Вывести все изображения при помощи wp_get_attachment_link

Tags: php, wordpress

Хочу вывести все изображения которые были добавлены, но сейчас отображается только одно. 'sertificates_gallery' - ID галереи из Advanced Custom Fields. Пробовал также через foreach, но видимо каких-то параметров не хватает, чтобы выводить именно изображения. Вот код:

```
<?php 
    $image = get_field('sertificates_gallery');
    $size = 'thumbnail'; 

    if( $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_link( $image, $size );
    }

    else {
        echo "Пока еще нет сертификатов";
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: Нашел ответ

```
if( $images ): ?>
  <div class="images">
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
      <?php echo $image['thumbnail_image_url']; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php else : ?>
  Пока еще нет сертификатов
<?php endif; ?>
```